# How to place two elements in a row while using .each loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-3, each

I want to show two columns of the code in table data tag"" per row while using '.each' method. But the issue is that the following code displays one column in a row.

```
<table>
  <% @lease.apartment.roommates.each do |roommate| %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <% unless roommate == @lease.second_occupant || roommate == @lease.user %>        
          <% if roommate.current_room.present? %>
            <p>
              <%= roommate.full_name %> - 
              <% if roommate.current_room.apartment == @lease.apartment%>
                <%= roommate.current_room&.label %> 
              <% end %>
              <br>Email:<%= roommate.email %><br>Phone:<%= roommate.phone %><br>
              <% if @lease.end_at.present? %>
                Lease End date (if applicable):<%= @lease.end_at %>
              <% end %>
            </p>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not clear if you want to display the same name twice on a row, or two different name son a row. Can you clarify?

Comment: @BenFennner! Two different names in a row...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [each_slice](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) method for dividing the array into slices of 2 elements each:

```
<table>
  <% @roommates.each_slice(2) do |roommate_slice| %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">            
        <%= roommate_slice[0].full_name %>
        <%= roommate_slice[1].full_name %>
      </td>      
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please have a look again at the edited question? I want to display two columns in a row...